# Set all radio buttons to either true or false in osCommerce, or just the one as true?

Tags: php, oscommerce

I added some radio buttons to a PHP form in osCommerce. I plan on adding a bunch more but in the meantime I have four right now. I'm wondering if I need to set all the radio buttons as true/false or just the single instance I want as true.

Here's the code I have:

```
if (!isset($pInfo->tab_id)) $pInfo->tab_id = '1';

switch ($pInfo->tab_id) {
  case '0': $none_tab_id = true; $shirt_tab_id = false; 
            $coverall_tab_id = false; $glove_tab_id = false; 
            break;
  case '1': $coverall_tab_id = true; $shirt_tab_id = false; 
            $none_tab_id = false; $glove_tab_id = false; 
            break;
  case '2': $coverall_tab_id = false; $shirt_tab_id = true; 
            $none_tab_id = false; $glove_tab_id = false; 
            break;
  case '3': $glove_tab_id = true; $coverall_tab_id = false; 
            $shirt_tab_id = false; $none_tab_id = false; 
            break;
   default: $coverall_tab_id = false; $shirt_tab_id = true; 
            $none_tab_id = false;
}
```

.

```
<?php 

echo '&nbsp;None' . tep_draw_radio_field('tab_id', '0', $none_tab_id) . 
     '&nbsp;coveralls' . tep_draw_radio_field('tab_id', '1', $coverall_tab_id) .
     '&nbsp;Shirts' .tep_draw_radio_field('tab_id', '2', $shirt_tab_id) . 
     '&nbsp;Gloves' . tep_draw_radio_field('tab_id', '3', $glove_tab_id); 

?>
```

osCommerce defines the `tep_draw_radio_field` function as this:

```
tep_draw_radio_field($name, $value = '', $checked = false, $compare = '')
```

Is it necessary to set all the variables to `false` in each case or if can I just set the one I want to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `tep_draw_radio_field()` function the only required parameter is the name variable, of which the radio button will use.

The rest of the arguments are optional and have [defaults already set for them](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default).

You don't need to code all of the radio buttons to either true or false. The default argument is `false` and any that aren't explicitly set when you call the function will be set as such.

Just set the one you need to be true as `true`. When you do, make doubly sure that it's also the third argument.

Comment: Thank you I don't know why I didn't just try that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do something like this?

```
if (!isset($pInfo->tab_id)) $pInfo->tab_id = '1';

$none_tab_id = ($pInfo->tab_id == '0');
$coverall_tab_id = ($pInfo->tab_id == '1');
$shirt_tab_id = ($pInfo->tab_id == '2');
$glove_tab_id = ($pInfo->tab_id == '3');

if(!($none_tab_id || $coverall_tab_id || $glove_tab_id || $shirt_tab_id)) {
    $shirt_tab_id = true;
}
```

Comment: What is the 3rd portion for? if(!($none_tab_id || $coverall_tab_id || $glove_tab_id || $shirt_tab_id)) {
    $shirt_tab_id = true;

Answer (score 0):

You could tighten up the switch statement:

```
$none_tab_id = false; 
$shirt_tab_id = false;                 
$coverall_tab_id = false; 
$glove_tab_id = false; 
switch ($pInfo->tab_id) {
  case '0': $none_tab_id = true; 
            break;
  case '1': $coverall_tab_id = true; 
            break;
  case '2': $shirt_tab_id = true; 
            break;
  case '3': $glove_tab_id = true;  
            break;
   default: $shirt_tab_id = true; 

}
```

Comment: Thanks that would work too but apparently I don't even need to set them as false.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to code all of the radio buttons to either true or false. The default argument is false and any that aren't explicitly set when you call the function will be set as such.

Just set the one you need to be true as true. When you do, make doubly sure that it's also the third argument.